# Merge elements with same attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have an xml document:

```
<bans>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#1">
    <login>user1</login>
    <reason>reason one</reason>
  </ban>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#1">
    <login>user1</login>
    <reason>reason two</reason>
  </ban>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#1">
    <login>user2</login>
    <reason>reason three</reason>
  </ban>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#2">
    <login>user1</login>
    <reason>reason four</reason>
  </ban>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#1">
    <login>user2</login>
    <reason>reason five</reason>
  </ban>
</bans>
```

How to merge with xslt all `ban` elements where `job` attribute and `login` value are same and select `reason` value from the latest?

In this example I want to merge first with second `ban` elements because they both has `job="gh:test/test#1"` and `<login>user1</login>` and third with fifth, so the result of transformation should be this:

```
<bans>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#1">
    <login>user1</login>
    <reason>reason two</reason>
  </ban>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#2">
    <login>user1</login>
    <reason>reason four</reason>
  </ban>
  <ban job="gh:test/test#1">
    <login>user2</login>
    <reason>reason five</reason>
  </ban>
</bans>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What version of xslt? This looks more like a grouping question where you’re just outputting the last item in the group. If there’s more to the xml and it really does need to be a merge, can you please update the input/output examples to show the merging of different elements between `ban`’s?

Comment: This is a standard grouping question, and the best solution therefore depends strongly on which version of XSLT you are using, which you forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 you can use `<xsl:for-each-group select="ban" group-by="@job, login" composite="yes">`:

[xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-for-each-group)

> If either of the `group-by` or `group-adjacent` attributes is present, then for each item in the population a set of **grouping keys** is calculated, as follows: the expression contained in the `group-by` or `group-adjacent` attribute is evaluated; the result is atomized; and any `xs:untypedAtomic` values are cast to `xs:string`.
>
> If `composite="yes"` is specified, there is a single grouping key whose value is the resulting sequence; otherwise, there is a set of grouping keys, consisting of the distinct atomic values present in the result sequence.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="bans">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="ban" composite="yes" group-by="@job, login">
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[last()]"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4ks